# Mudar retorno /Date(1386295200000)/ para formato data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework

Tenho um retorno de `json` que vem assim do `SqlServer`:

```
/Date(1386295200000)/
```

Como converter para o formato data `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Comment: Você tentou alguma forma ? Seria conversão da data unix para `dd/mm/yyyy` correto !?

Comment: não, porque nunca tinha visto esse retorno na vida...  nem sabia que era data unix hue, sim seria

Comment: Isso vem dinamico do entity.

Comment: Se está utilizando qual backend (linguagem de programação)?

Comment: Estou usando o c# como backend

Comment: Você quer mostrar isto em uma página HTML e ele está vindo do Json?

Comment: Está usando Entity Framework com aspnet mvc?

Comment: Isso, ambos estão certos meus caros

Comment: É sql server mesmo @gabrielfalieri ?

Comment: Sim, sql server

Comment: Ai você está retornando para o seu Front-End e não tem o formato, talvez uma simples conversão no próprio controller resolva, ou até um ViewModel para isso também resolva se tem o controller ai?

Comment: Siim, tenho o controller

Comment: Dentro do AsQueryable tem algo que posso fazer que possa fazer essa conversão?

Comment: e a versão do Entity Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A opção melhor nesse caso é herda a classe `JsonResult` e mudar a configuração do formato da data, da seguinte forma:

***Classe*** `JsonResultDateFormat`:

```
public class JsonResultDateFormat : JsonResult
{        
    public JsonResultDateFormat(object data, 
            JsonRequestBehavior jsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)    
    {
        Data = data;
        JsonRequestBehavior = jsonRequestBehavior;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        if (ContentEncoding != null) response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;
        JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(response.Output) { 
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented 
        };
        JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            DateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy" // aqui o formato da data
        });
        serializer.Serialize(writer, Data);
        writer.Flush();
    }

    public static JsonResultDateFormat Create(object data, 
                JsonRequestBehavior jsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
        => new JsonResultDateFormat(data, jsonRequestBehavior);
}
```

***e no método do*** `Controller`:

```
public JsonResult Test()
{
    using (DatabasecoreContext c = new DatabasecoreContext())
    {
        var data = c.Notice.ToList();
        return JsonResultDateFormat.Create(data);
    }
}
```

***a sua saída é***:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "CreditId": 1,
    "Title": "Esporte",
    "DateCreated": "01/02/2018"
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "CreditId": 2,
    "Title": "Esporte",
    "DateCreated": "01/02/2018"
  }
]
```

<sub>***Referencia:*** [Dealing with JSON Dates in ASP.NET MVC](https://www.developer.com/net/dealing-with-json-dates-in-asp.net-mvc.html)</sub>

Comment: Vou testar essa sua soluçao aqui agora

Comment: Perfeita @virgilio-novic

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que você está fazendo uma chamada Json e tem um campo data, igual ao Json abaixo:

```
{  
   "rows":[  
      {  
         "UsuarioConviteID":1,
         "Email":"email@gmail.com",
         "Controle":"Aceito",
         "DtControle":"\/Date(1518540878497)\/",
         "DtCad":"\/Date(1518526866667)\/",
         "Status":"A",
         "Fixo":"Não"
      }
   ],
   "total":1
}
```

Para você converter data usando JQuery pode usar a função:

```
function formataData(value) {
    if (value == null)
        return null;    
    var dataTexto = value.replace('/', '').replace('/', '').replace('Date', '').replace('(', '').replace(')', '');
    var date = new Date(parseInt(dataTexto));    
    return pad(2, date.getDate().toString(), '0') + "/" + pad(2, (date.getMonth() + 1).toString(), '0') + "/" + pad(4, date.getFullYear().toString(), '0');
};
```

Comment: Aonde que usária ela para exibir em um bootgrid por exemplo

Comment: @gabrielfalieri só um instante para ver o funcionamento do bootgrid

Comment: @gabrielfalieri se você olhar a documentação do bootgrid em http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Examples#data você tem uma função ``formatters: {
        "link": function(column, row)
        {
            return "<a href=\"#\">" + column.id + ": " + row.id + "</a>";
        }`` lá você poderia colocar a função

Answer (score 2):

A biblioteca ***`Momentjs`*** já suporta ***`ASP.NET JSON Date`***, veja a [documentação](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/).

*Exemplo de código:*

```
moment("/Date(1386295200000)/").format("DD/MM/YYYY"); // 06/12/2013
moment("/Date(1198908717056-0700)/"); // Sat Dec 29 2007 04:11:57 GMT-0200
moment("/Date(1198908717056-0700)/").format("DD/MM/YYYY"); // 29/12/2007
```

Veja o resultado:

```js
$(function() {
  var result = moment('/Date(1386295200000)/').format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  alert(result);
  result = moment("/Date(1198908717056-0700)/");
  alert(result);
  result = moment("/Date(1198908717056-0700)/").format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  alert(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.11.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Ou se preferir em [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgjf7rsm/250/).

Answer (score 1):

Do lado do servidor a data provavelmente está correta. Geralmente isso acontece na conversão de `DateTime` para `Json` (e geralmente tratamos o retorno em `JavaScript`, não sei se é o seu caso, a questão não aborda isso).

Se quiser fazer o ajuste só no lado do front-end via javascript, crie uma função assim:

```
function ConverterJsonDateToJavascriptDate(data)
{
    var retorno = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
}
```

Use assim:

```
var jsonDate = "/Date(1386295200000)/"; 
var resultado = ConverterJsonDateToJavascriptDate(jsonDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo o uso do framework [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com) para fazer tratamento de datas. 
Segue um exemplo de extraído da documentação do [Bootgrid](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Documentation#converters)

```js
$("#grid").bootgrid({
    converters: {
        datetime: {
            from: function (value) { return moment(value); },
            to: function (value) { return value.format("lll"); }
        }
    }
});
```

Outra alternativa é controlar saída da data, usando o JsonProperty annotation :

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

namespace WebApiDemo.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/values
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var demo = new DemoViewModel { Data = DateTime.UtcNow };
            return Ok(demo);
        }
    }

    public class DemoViewModel
    {
        [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(IsoDateTimeConverter))]
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```