# Como converter uma data no formato C# `/Date(1504020443813-0300)/` para PHP?

Tags: php, data

Em algumas aplicações que uso `C#`, quando retorno o valor em `JSON`, o objeto `DateTime` é serializado para um formato esquisitinho, mais ou menos assim:

```
/Date(1504020443813-0300)/
```

E eu vou receber isso em PHP.

Quando eu for receber esse valor em PHP, vou precisar convertê-lo para o objeto `DateTime`.

Sendo assim, como eu posso converter esse formato aí para `DateTime` do PHP? Já tem alguma coisa nativa do PHP, ou tem que usar `regex` ou coisas do tipo?

Comment: É isso https://stackoverflow.com/a/46120602/1518921 ? No caso converte em um formato valido pelo "ISO" e passar via string, ai o PHP vai entender no uso do DateTime ;)

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/305454/112052

Comment: @hkotsubo essa seria melhor https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/285942/3635 - a resposta que vc linkou resolve no PHP, o que achei uma solução meio desastrosa

Comment: @ThiagoMagalhães veja o meu comentário anterior

Comment: Solução resumida: https://ideone.com/nFROOE